# Authenticating Twitter API using OAuth1 through Azure API Management

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, azure-api-management

I'm trying to pass the Twitter search API through Azure API Management but am not able to authenticate.  Based on the research I've done so far I may need to provide a policy on the backend to do so but I really don't have any experience with that and am curious if someone has successfully configured the Twitter API through Azure API Management.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
{
"openapi": "3.0.1",
"info": {
    "title": "TwitterAPI",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0"
},
"servers": [{
    "url": "****"
}],
"paths": {
    "/1.1/search/tweets.json": {
        "get": {
            "summary": "Search",
            "description": "Search Twitter",
            "operationId": "search",
            "parameters": [{
                "name": "query",
                "in": "query",
                "description": "One query/rule/filter for matching Tweets. Up to 512 characters.",
                "required": true,
                "schema": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "max_results",
                "in": "query",
                "description": "The maximum number of search results to be returned by a request.",
                "schema": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
        "apiKeyHeader": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
            "in": "header"
        },
        "apiKeyQuery": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "name": "subscription-key",
            "in": "query"
        }
    }
},
"security": [{
    "apiKeyHeader": []
}, {
    "apiKeyQuery": []
}]
```

Comment: Well why not put a logic app in between and have the request fo through the logic app as backend for the api management

Comment: Thanks for the response - do you know if that's possible to do using the keys and secrets from Twitter to authenticate?  All examples I saw using logic apps used the username and password which I won't be given access to.